# Create a login page avoiding the other pages

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm quite new on angular and I was creating a login page, my problem is I'd like to create a login page without show any other components besind and once I got the response 200 redirect to the other component:

my app.component.html is:

```
 <nav>
  <p-tabView (onChange)="onClick($event)">
    <p-tabPanel header="Random " routerLink="/random" >
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Manifacture" routerLink="/Manifacture">
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Add" routerLink="/add">
    </p-tabPanel>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </p-tabView>
</nav>
```

my app.router:

```
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'random', component: RandomPComponent },
  { path: 'Manufacuter', component: ManufactureComponent }
....
```

What can I see on my angular is:
[image: Main page]

I know the problem is my main page with the tab-view componet but I want are invisible until is logged in, and I'd like to know if is correct to add the tab-view in the app.component or shoud I create another component (and an other router) to show as I want

Thanks to all, I really appreciate

Comment: why not hide them with simple `ngIf='loggedIn'` I'm not sure if you are asking about hiding those tabs or not letting user open those URLs or both. Because I can just do `/Manufacuter` and go to manufacture page.

Comment: @Prajwal Thanks for answering, yeah, one main problem is the user can see the tabs and can even do /Manifacuter... I thought about ngIf... but I wasn't sure if the logic can go in app.module.html

Comment: Please check https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access  you can make use of this to cover direct entry cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access) to redirect to login page

```
export class IsLoggedGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, 
          private router: Router, 
          private activatedRouter: ActivatedRoute) { }

  canActivate(activatedRouteSnapshot:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         routerStateSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
     return this.loginService.isLogged().pipe(
       map((res: any) => {
         ...
         return res.success;
       }),
       tap(res => {
         if (!res)
         {
           this.router.navigate(['/login'], 
             { queryParams: { returnUrl: routerStateSnapshot.url } });
         }
       }))
    } 
}
```

Then you can to have a app.component

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And a main.component like your "old app.component"

```
<nav>
  <p-tabView (onChange)="onClick($event)">
    ....
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </p-tabView>
</nav>
```

So, you can use a router like

```
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component:MainComponent, canActivate: [IsLoggedGuard ] 
      children:[
         { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
         { path: 'random', component: RandomPComponent },
         { path: 'Manufacuter', component: ManufactureComponent }
      ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my Opinion the best way is to use the [ngIf directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) and display your tabView when you user is log using a boolean value.

Concerning you app-component, i think that is better to have another component like a layout and only let your router outlet on app-comp

Comment: Yeah! I think is the best idea, just asking I should left just  <router-outlet></router-outlet> on the app-component.html?

Comment: There another approach that is use [route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access) and a path '' with children

Comment: I agree that the route guards is the best solution